# Display Sensordata in webpage

Tags: python, node.js, ajax, rest, webserver

I am retrieving temperature data from a sensor continuously. Now I want to display them in a webpage hosted by a node.js webserver. I struggle to understand how these data are beeing send to my html webpage because there are many ways doing that without making any way clear for me. I read in this context terms like REST, AJAX, POST and GET.

Can someone make it clear for me which would be the easiest choice in that case.

Answer (score 1):

All those terms are connected with one another:
REST is a software architecture used for creating web-services that allows a requesting system (e.g. your browser) to access and/or manipulate data on the server.
GET and POST are two HTTP methods that define what you want to do to the data on the server (get it, change it, add something, ...).
[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) is used on the client-side to retrieve data from RESTfull services.

In your case, you would create a GET endpoint in node.js (with e.g. express) and then connect to this endpoint via Ajax to retrieve the data and display it to your website.